Is this proof of the angle bisector theorem known?
Given a triangle $ABC$, let $D$ be the point of intersection of the side $BC$ with the bisector of the angle $A$. Then $|AB|/|AC|=|DB|/|DC|$.
This statement is known as the angle bisector theorem.
Is the following proof of it known?
Proof: The case when $AD\perp BC$ is obvious.
Otherwise, let $D'$ be the point on the line through $A$ and $D$ such that $D'$ is distinct from $D$ and $|D'C|=|DC|$. Then, looking at the "solid" and "dashed" angles in the following picture, we see that triangles $ABD$ and $ACD'$ are similar. Hence, $|AB|/|AC|=|DB|/|D'C|=|DB|/|DC|$. $\quad\Box$


See also http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/ABisector.shtml

+1. I don't know if it's novel (I suspect it isn't ... but that doesn't diminish your accomplishment in discovering it), but I like it as an uncluttered alternative to drawing perpendiculars, as in Proofs 1 and 2 on Cut-the-Knot's "Angle Bisector Theorem" page. Note: $D'$ cannot be chosen distinct from $D$ when $BC\perp AD$ (ie, when $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles with base $BC$). So, a slight refinement of the description of your construction is in order to be completely inclusive. ... Cheers!

@Blue : Thank you for your comment. The case $AD\perp BC$ is now included.

Very elegant.${}$

I have finally found this proof in the literature. It is on pp. 60--61 of Plane Geometry
by Daniel Tell Sigley and William Timothy, Stratton, 1948.
So, the answer to the posted question is yes. However, there seems to be no information in that book concerning sources of this proof. It would be nice to get such information.

This seems a good approach.
Euclid proves the angle bisector theorem in Elements VI, 3 before developing the theory of similar triangles.  But his theory of similar triangles does not require Prop. VI, 3, which in fact is not used in the rest of Elements.
Euclid proves VI, 3 as soon as he can (it requires VI, 2), but not because he needs it for any later theorem. So it seems that, logically if not aesthetically, he could have placed it in Book VI after the theorems on similar triangles, as OP’s proof requires.

Thank you for your answer. Euclid's proof is really elegant. It's strange that Wikipedia does not include it.
